# How to check for 2 different values and delete the text where either of these values are found?

Tags: vba

I want to find "Ext" and "/" in a column of data and delete all the text after and including those characters
If it doesn't find those characters in my data then exit the sub

I can do them separately but I definitely over complicated it, there must be an easier way

The data column will also have blanks in so I have to avoid blank cells and check the whole range of data

Code

```
Sub DeleteAfterText()
    Dim rngFoundCell As Range
    Set rngFoundCell = Sheets("User Load").Range("E1:E3000").Find(What:="Ext")
    'This is checking to see if the range contains EXT, if not it exits the sub'
    If rngFoundCell Is Nothing Then 'If no cell in the range has an ' then exist sub
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Worksheets("User Load").Range("E1000").Select 'Start from bottom'
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select  'This selects the bottom to the top'
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "Phone Number"    'This does the change until it reaches the header name'
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then     'If the cell is blank it skips it as there is no action after the then'
            Else
                ActiveCell = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "Ext")(0)
                'ActiveCell = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "/")(0)
            End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Loop    
    End If
End Sub

Sub DeleteAfterText2()
    Dim rngFoundCell As Range
    Set rngFoundCell = Sheets("User Load").Range("E1:E3000").Find(What:="/")
    'This is checking to see if the range contains EXT, if not it exits the sub'
    If rngFoundCell Is Nothing Then 'If no cell in the range has an ' then exist sub
    Exit Sub
    Else
        Worksheets("User Load").Range("E1000").Select 'Start from bottom'
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select  'This selects the bottom to the top'
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "Phone Number"    'This does the change until it reaches the header name'
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then     'If the cell is blank it skips it as there is no action after the then'
            Else
                ActiveCell = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "/")(0)
            End If
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Loop    
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work. It is simple to read and easy to understand.

```
    Option Explicit

    'The calling Sub
    Sub main()
        DeleteTextFromColumn ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E3000")
    End Sub

    Sub DeleteTextFromColumn(ByRef inRange As Range)

        Dim cCell As Range
        Dim intPos1 As Integer
        Dim intPos2 As Integer
        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim strOut As String

        'You can specify which column if more than one column is provided to the
        '  subroutine. Ex: Range("E1:F3000")
        For Each cCell In inRange.Columns(1).Cells
            strTemp = cCell.Value
            'gets the position of "ext" (case insensitive)
            intPos1 = InStr(LCase(strTemp), "ext")
            'gets the position of "/"
            intPos2 = InStr(strTemp, "/")

            strOut = strTemp
            If intPos1 > 1 Then
                strOut = Mid(strTemp, 1, intPos1 - 1)
            ElseIf intPos2 > 1 Then
                strOut = Mid(strTemp, 1, intPos2 - 1)
            End If

            'Outputs the results
            cCell.Value = strOut
        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best to break out repeated code into a sub which has parameters for the variable parts of the operation.

You can do something like this:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim theRange As Range
    Set theRange = Sheets("User Load").Range("E1:E3000")
    RemoveTextAfter theRange, "Ext"
    RemoveTextAfter theRange, "/"
End Sub

Sub RemoveTextAfter(rng As Range, findWhat As String)
    Dim f As Range
    If Len(findWhat) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Set f = rng.Find(What:="Ext", lookat:=xlPart)
    Do While Not f Is Nothing
        f.Value = Split(f.Value, findWhat)(0)
        Set f = rng.Find(What:="Ext", lookat:=xlPart)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you two answers for the price of one. :)

At its root, the basic logic you need to figure out if a substring exists in a given string is a standard part of VBA in the [`InStr` function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php). Using this, you can break out your logic to check a cell's value and (conditionally) delete the remainder of the string into a function like this:

```
Private Function DeleteTextAfter(ByVal contents As String, _
                                 ByVal token As String) As String
    '--- searches the given string contents and if it finds the given token
    '    it deletes the token and all following characters
    DeleteTextAfter = contents

    Dim pos1 As Long
    pos1 = InStr(1, contents, token, vbTextCompare)
    If pos1 > 0 Then
        DeleteTextAfter = Left(contents, pos1 - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Notice here that using the function created above, we don't need to use `Range.Find` at all.

Once you have that, your top-level logic consists of setting up the range to search. In all of my code, I explicitly create objects to reference the workbook and worksheet so that I can keep things straight. In a simple example like this, it may seem like overkill, but the habit comes in handy when your code gets more involved. So I set up the range like this

```
Dim thisWB As Workbook
Dim userLoadWS As Worksheet
Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
Set userLoadWS = thisWB.Sheets("User Load")

Dim searchRange As Range
Set searchRange = userLoadWS.Range("E1:E3000")
```

Now the loop just goes through each cell and gets a (potentially) updated value.

```
Dim cell As Variant
For Each cell In searchRange
    If Not cell.value = vbNullString Then
        Debug.Print cell.Address & " = " & cell.value
        cell.value = DeleteTextAfter(cell.value, "Ext")
        cell.value = DeleteTextAfter(cell.value, "/")
    End If
Next cell
```

So your whole solution looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestDirectlyFromRange()
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Dim userLoadWS As Worksheet
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set userLoadWS = thisWB.Sheets("User Load")

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Set searchRange = userLoadWS.Range("E1:E3000")

    Dim cell As Variant
    For Each cell In searchRange
        If Not cell.value = vbNullString Then
            Debug.Print cell.Address & " = " & cell.value
            cell.value = DeleteTextAfter(cell.value, "Ext")
            cell.value = DeleteTextAfter(cell.value, "/")
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Private Function DeleteTextAfter(ByVal contents As String, _
                                 ByVal token As String) As String
    '--- searches the given string contents and if it finds the given token
    '    it deletes the token and all following characters
    DeleteTextAfter = contents

    Dim pos1 As Long
    pos1 = InStr(1, contents, token, vbTextCompare)
    If pos1 > 0 Then
        DeleteTextAfter = Left(contents, pos1 - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

But wait, there's more!!

You're iterating over 3,000 rows of data. That can get to be slow if all those rows are filled or if you increase the number of rows to search. To speed up the search, the answer is to copy the data in the range to a [memory-based array](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array) first, modify any of the data, then copy the results back. This example uses the same `Function DeleteTextAfter` as above and is much quicker. Use whichever one fits your situation best.

```
Public Sub TestRangeInArray()
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Dim userLoadWS As Worksheet
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set userLoadWS = thisWB.Sheets("User Load")

    '--- create the range and copy into a memory array
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim searchData As Variant
    Set searchRange = userLoadWS.Range("E1:E3000")
    searchData = searchRange.value

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(searchData, 1) To UBound(searchData, 1)
        If Not searchData(i, 1) = vbNullString Then
            searchData(i, 1) = DeleteTextAfter(searchData(i, 1), "Ext")
            searchData(i, 1) = DeleteTextAfter(searchData(i, 1), "/")
        End If
    Next i

    '--- now copy the modified array back to the worksheet range
    searchRange.value = searchData
End Sub
```